# Avoid overflow with softplus function in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to implement the following softplus function:

```
log(1 + exp(x))
```

I've tried it with math/numpy and float64 as data type, but whenever `x` gets too large (e.g. `x = 1000`) the result is `inf`.

Can you assist me on how to successfully handle this function with large numbers?

Answer (score 23):

**TLDR:**

```py
import numpy as np
import math

def softplus_np(x): return np.log1p(np.exp(-np.abs(x))) + np.maximum(x, 0)
def softplus_math(x): return math.log1p(math.exp(-abs(x))) + max(x, 0)
```

**Explanation:**
There is a relation which one can use:

```
log(1+exp(x)) = log(1+exp(x)) - log(exp(x)) + x = log(1+exp(-x)) + x
```

So a safe implementation, as well as mathematically sound, would be:

```
log(1+exp(-abs(x))) + max(x,0)
```

This works both for `math` and `numpy` functions (use e.g.: `np.log`, `np.exp`, `np.abs`, `np.maximum`).

Comment: have you tried this? there is no 'log' function in native python

Comment: True, I wanted to stick close to the question, which also did not specify in the code snippet which package is actually used. You can use the numpy, or the math package to make it working python code. I edited the answer to make it clear!

Comment: For anyone wondering, the numpy implementation is `np.log(1 + np.exp(-np.abs(x))) + np.maximum(x,0)`

Comment: For simplicity, `np.log1p(np.exp(-np.abs(x))) + np.maximum(x, 0)`

Comment: what about underflow?

Comment: There is no underflow happening. If `x` is very small, then `e=exp(x)` is super small and really fast zero wrt. some floating point precision. Underflow would mean, that the theoretically result `log(1+e)=log(1+exp(x))` would be non-zero in this case. However `log(1+e)` is roughly `e` for small e, therefor there is no loss of precision for small `x`.

Answer (score 9):

Since for `x>30` we have `log(1+exp(x)) ~= log(exp(x)) = x`, a simple stable implementation is

```
def safe_softplus(x, limit=30):
  if x>limit:
    return x
  else:
    return np.log1p(np.exp(x))
```

In fact `| log(1+exp(30)) - 30 | < 1e-10`, so this implementation makes errors smaller than `1e-10` and never overflows. In particular for x=1000 the error of this approximation will be much smaller than float64 resolution, so it is impossible to even measure it on the computer.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use np.log1p?

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use [`numpy.logaddexp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) with 0 as the first argument.  That is, `softplus(x)` (or `log1pexp(x)`) is equivalent to `np.logaddexp(0, x)`.  It will avoid the overflow problem that the naive implementation has.  For example,

```
In [506]: import numpy as np

In [507]: x = 2.5

In [508]: np.log1p(np.exp(x))  # Naive implementation
Out[508]: 2.5788897342925496

In [509]: np.logaddexp(0, x)
Out[509]: 2.5788897342925496

In [510]: x = 20

In [511]: np.log1p(np.exp(x))
Out[511]: 20.000000002061153

In [512]: np.logaddexp(0, x)
Out[512]: 20.000000002061153

In [513]: x = 1000  # exp(x) in the naive implementation will overflow with x this large.

In [514]: np.log1p(np.exp(x))
<ipython-input-514-1647fa2e1120>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp
  np.log1p(np.exp(x))
Out[514]: inf

In [515]: np.logaddexp(0, x)
Out[515]: 1000.0
```

Comment: ^ this is clearly the best solution among proposed

Answer (score 0):

i use this code to work in arrays

```
def safe_softplus(x):
    inRanges = (x < 100)
    return np.log(1 + np.exp(x*inRanges))*inRanges + x*(1-inRanges)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm currently using (slightly inefficient but clean and vectorized):

```
def safe_softplus(x, limit=30):
    return np.where(x>limit, x, np.log1p(np.exp(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using TensorFlow, you can simply use the `tf.math.softplus`.