# Is there a way to get every element of a list without using loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I found this task in a book of my prof:

```
def f(x):
    return f = log(exp(z))

def problem(M: List)
    return np.array([f(x) for x in M])
```

How do I implement a solution?

Comment: Where are you using `M`?

Comment: Use the numpy operations on the array *after* you convert the list

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can't you just do `np.log(1 + np.exp(np.array(M)))`?

Comment: @Priyatham Yes. `np.log1p(np.exp(M))` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy is all about performing operations on entire arrays. Your professor is expecting you to use that functionality.

Start by converting your list `M`  into array `z`:

```
z = np.array(M)
```

Now you can do elementwise operations like `exp` and log:

```
e = np.exp(z)
f = 1 + e
g = np.log(f)
```

The functions [`np.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) and [`np.log`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) are applied to each element of an array. If the input is not an array, it will be converted into one.

Operations like `1 + e` work on an entire array as well, in this case using the magic of [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). Since `1` is a scalar, it can unambiguously expanded to the same shape as `e`, and added as if by [`np.add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html).

Normally, the sequence of operations can be compactified into  a single line, similarly to what you did in your initial attempt. You can reduce the number of operations slightly by using [`np.log1p`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log1p.html):

```
def f(x):
    return np.log1p(np.exp(x))
```

Notice that I did not convert `x` to an array first since `np.exp` will do that for you.

A fundamental problem with this naive approach is that `np.exp` will overflow for values that we would expect to get reasonable results. This can be solved using the technique in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51828104/2988730) answer:

```
def f(x):
    return np.log1p(np.exp(-np.abs(x))) + np.maximum(x, 0)
```

Comment: @susanne. Here is a question addressing your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44230635/2988730. Just replace the formula with the one in the accepted answer. The comments tell you how to do it specifically in numpy.